# Does the author of an answer retain copyright?

Tags: discussion, legal

This is pretty straightforward. I have answered various questions on Stack Exchange. I'd like to potentially reuse the content of those answers elsewhere. If I retain the copyright to my answers, then I can do so, whereas if Stack Exchange now owns the copyright, then I cannot – at least not without Stack Exchange's permission. Thus, I'd like to know if I retain the copyright to my answers or not.

Ancillary question: I've tagged this as a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) question, but it has a pretty clear-cut answer; none of the other tags seemed relevant. Is there some other place to ask clear-cut "meta" questions about Stack Exchange?

Comment: Yes. This is completely spelled out in the TOS. (Specifically, content entirely created by you is exempted from the attribution rules). You don't need SO's permission to reuse **any** content on the site, even that created by others, although you do need to follow the license terms.

Comment: From the bottom of every page on the site: "user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required"

Comment: @gunr2171: "user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required" doesn't really answer the question – that's how it's licensed, not who owns it.

Comment: @Wooble: "content entirely created by you is exempted from the attribution rules" – it's not actually exempted. Since you own the copyright – as Louis so helpfully clarified – then you can do anything you want with the content and don't need a license. The license only applies to those who do not already own the content, i.e. everyone else (including Stack Exchange).

Comment: @StefanKarpinski: it's exempted from the section of the terms of use of the site that deal with attribution. These rules aren't part of the license (and some would argue that the nofollow clause of the TOS violates CC-by-sa and isn't valid.) A clause that actually tried to stop you from using your own content elsewhere would quite likely be unenforceable, of course :) .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) say:

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably **licensed** to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable **right and license** to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You.

(Emphasis added.)

Anything you contribute which is yours in the first place remains yours. You could publish it any way you want. You've merely given a license to SE and others to use what you've posted here.

(In case someone wonders: the word "right" in "right and license" is not a transfer of copyright.)

And finally: I'm not a lawyer. If this kind of stuff keeps you up at night, talk to a lawyer who specializes in intellectual property law.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I personally don't care, but you don't want to write a book (or something like that) and later find out that you have inadvertently illegally plagiarized your "own" content, now owned by someone else, unbeknownst to you. This seems to be a well-thought-out policy, since claiming outright ownership would discourage experts from contributing answers directly on the site.